# How to merge vertical and horizontal menu

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, html

I want to display the menu should be like this in the screenshot 
[image: screenshot 1]

the submenu's submenu should be full height.

[image: screenshot 2]

My menu is showing like in the above screenshot.

Comment: can you provide the link? so we can inspect the css

Comment: Please refer for the proper fomat of a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove relative position from the submenu li and give it to the parent menu. That way your code will work just as you wanted.